# Objective C Socket connection IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, сокет, iphone, tcp

Делаю клиент IOS для сервера на Java. Все отлично, решил сделать проверку работы сервера перед каждым запросом(а они отсылаются каждую секунду + по нажатиям пользователя). Когда сервер в локальной сети и выключен - все хорошо. Но когда пытаешься подключится по адресу, которого нету (к примеру выключил wi-fi сеть). То весь процесс замерзает на методе `[outputstream write:...]`, какие только я статусе потока не проверял - не заметил на что можно опереться.

Также я каждый раз создаю новое подключение перед отправкой/приемом вместо `- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {}`. Так как нужно отправлять разные запросы когда пользователь использует разные контролы + каждую секунду. Есть вариант со стеком, но думаю не лучший вариант.

Прошу помогите избежать этого вечного ожидания на методе `[outputstream write:...]`!

Если что вот код метода который вызывается каждую секунду :

```
-(void) refreshData{

NSInputStream *inputStream ;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;

[NSStream getStreamsToHostWithName:@"172.20.10.3" port:8080 inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

Request * req = [[Request alloc] initWithCommand:10];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[[req getJsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength: [data length]];
[outputStream close];

uint8_t buf[1024];
NSString *s;
int len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
if(len<0){
    [timer invalidate ];
    timer = nil;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bad connection" message:@"No connection with address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Repeat", nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

if(len > 0) {
    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

}

Response *response = [[Response alloc] initWithJson:s];

 // удалены действия связаные с ответом

[inputStream close];
```

}